# Run app built with SDK on pc without SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, exe

I wrote a small app built with the Microsoft Surface SDK in C# (.net 4 / 4.5), however people without the SDK seem to be unable to run the app.

I'm building it with Visual Studio 2012 and have `Local Copy` in the `Microsoft.Surface` reference set to `true`, but still nothing.

Is there any way that others can execute the app without installing the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Microsoft Surface Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716) which you should distribute along with your application.